# Writing VERTEX normals into an exported Collada (DAE) file

Tags: export, collada

Maybe I'm missing something, but I've tried everything I can to export a Collada file and have the number of normal vectors match the number of position vectors (and it never happens).

I just want my normal vectors to be one-to-one for the position vectors (and not the face normals, which will never be one-to-one).  In other words, I want the VERTEX normals exported, not the triangle face normals.

Blender doesn't seem to import these VERTEX normals correctly either, but that's a different issue.  I mean, I "get" it if Blender just doesn't use the vertex normals, but it has an option to show them, so it obviously knows how to calculate them.  It's my understanding that they're an average of all the face normals that touch/use any particular vertex (which makes sense).

Heck, if there's an add-in to just export these VERTEX normals to a text file, I'd even take that.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't write in all caps in the title or body of any posts, it is the written equivalent of shouting, is [harder to read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Readability) and may be [considered rude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Computing). Please use the [edit] button below the post to change you text into regular case.